# How to create a boxplot including a rating in different colors?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, multiple-columns, boxplot

[image]

I have a problem in handling the data. The topic is a rating of the sellers of meat. I want to see if the ratings are having an influence on the price of the meat.
I want to do a boxplot showing on x=meat y=price and with a boxplot showing in green the positive ratings and red the negative ratings.

If I use pivot.longer, the column will not have the correct effect having the amount of positive or negative ratings involved.

Comment: A boxplot is a summary plot of multiple datapoints for each x value. In your case there is only a single value, so it is not clear how you want to turn this into a boxplot?

Comment: Avoid using images to show your data. Instead, include a simple data frame, so that we can better understand your data and how to help you. Even still, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Would there be one boxplot or two? What parts of the boxplot should be colored -- the whole thing? the box? the whiskers? Do you want a scatterplot instead?

Comment: Hi Mario, I wand to show on the xaxis the meat and on the yaxis the price. Then I would like to show the boxplot according to the rating (Positive and negative). My problem is, that I do not know how the differenciate the diffences between the positive and negative ratings in terms of the number of ratings per meat. For example the fisrt meat seller has 23 positive ratings and 4 negative. How could I visualize this in my plot?

Comment: Hi Charlie, there should be two boxplots per meat. For the positive ratings in green, negative in red.

Answer (score 0):

Boxplots do not seem to be necessarily the best way to visualize this binary data. Here are a few examples how you could plot that data and perform a simple analysis of linear correlation between price and the fraction of positive ratings.

```r
# approximation of your data
mydf <- data.frame(meat=LETTERS[1:3], price=c(100, 23, 45), 
                   posR=c(23,2,6), negR=c(4,1,0))

# consider a barplot to show ratings:
barplot(cbind(posR, negR) ~ meat, data=mydf, col=c(2,1))
legend("topright", c("positive", "negative"), fill = c(2,1))
```

[image]

```r
mydf$fracPos <- with(mydf, posR/(posR + negR))

# plot positive fraction
with(mydf, barplot(cbind(fracPos, 1-fracPos) ~ meat, data=mydf, col=c(2,1)))
legend("right", c("positive", "negative"), fill = c(2,1))
```

[image]

```r
# calculate pearson correlation
lm1 <- lm(fracPos ~ price, data=mydf)

# plot average rating over price, add trendline and p-value of correlation
plot(fracPos ~ price, data=mydf, 
     sub=paste0("p=", sprintf("%.3g", summary(lm1)[[4]][[8]]), "; R.sq=", 
        sprintf("%.3g", summary(lm1)$r.squared)))
abline(coef(lm1), col="red")
```

[image]

If you still want to plot boxplots, keep in mind that the medians can only be one or the other binary value in this system. We are also determining the mean here and plotting it as well. In this example, positive ratings have been assigned a value of +1 and negative ratings of -1.

```r
# generating ratings vectors with +1 for pos and -1 for each neg rating
mydf$ratings <- apply(mydf, 1, function(x) c(rep(1, x[["posR"]]), rep(-1, x[["negR"]])))

# calculate mean rating
mydf$avgR <- sapply(mydf$ratings, mean)

# show boxplots with mean as a red dot
with(mydf, boxplot(setNames(ratings, meat)))
points(mydf$avgR, col="red", pch=18)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>